# Using Delegates In XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin.forms, resharper

When using an event on an element, I can just write the name of the EventHandler as string and it works: `<Button Click="OnButtonClick" ..>`. And even better, Visual Studio checks whether there really exists such an EventHandler in the code-behind. (This might be a feature of ReSharper, I'm not sure)

How can I do the same for a Func that I add to the element? (I am not considering using a Converter as I think it will require run-time reflection, which will slow things down. I am looking for a design-time solution like EventHandler)

I want a viewmodel property that returns a Func, and I want XAML to treat it like an event handler, or some close equivalent.

Comment: I've only been doing C# for ten years now, and WPF for only five; can you help me understand what is "a Func that I add to the element"? How are you adding it?

Comment: A class containing a property of type Func (it can be any type of delegate actually). In short, I am aiming for a handler with a return type.

Comment: You cannot bind a delegate to a XAML attribute directly - you must either wrap it in a method (which is what an event-handler is) or use a `{Binding }` with a TypeConverter to convert the `Func` to a `MethodInfo` (IIRC - though I'm not certain this would actually work). Ideally you should use `Command="{Binding }"` instead of `Click`, but that's another discussion).

Comment: Everything in XAML uses run-time reflection, by the way. Don't worry about the overhead in calling a *click event*, unless you anticipate the user clicking thousands of times a second. You can't do what you want out of the box; you need a command or an attached behavior. So, is this a property of the view or the viewmodel?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I also do not want to lose the design-time check that EventHandlers have in XAML.

Comment: Use command instead. you can't use Func.

Comment: @JohnL. With commands that's out of the question. With attached properties, you'd have to write a different attached property for each delegate type, if there's more than one. Maybe you could be more clear about your exact requirements. Some examples maybe.

Comment: @JohnL. "With a return type"? What are yo planning to do with the returned value?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a DependencyProperty.

Example:

```
class MyCoolButton : Button
{
    public Func<int, int> MyFunc
    {
        get { return (Func<int, int>)GetValue(MyFuncProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyFuncProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyFunc.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyFuncProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyFunc", typeof(Func<int, int>), typeof(MyCoolButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In your XAML you would set it:

```xml
<controls:MyCoolButton MyFunc="DoSomething" />
```

And in your code behind:

```
private int DoSomething(int foo)
{
    return foo++;
}
```

Calling the function from your cool button is as easy as

```
if (MyFunc != null)
{
    MyFunc(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question. but if you want EventHandler like in Button just use `public event EventHandler Clicked;`

```cs
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler Tapped;
}
```

I do suggest you to use Binding approach, instead of code-behind.